# Periferic or pressurizing pump to pull water up to a higher place?

Tags: water-pressure, pump

I live up a hill where the water doesn't always reach my tank. The pipe runs up a gentle slope and halfway it doesn't have enough pressure to reach us. Searching for a solution I seem to have two alternatives:

1. Place an intermediate tank where water does reach and add a periferic or centrifugal pump.
2. Directly attach a pressurizing pump to the pipe without a tank.

If I understand correctly, the pressurizing pump should give the incoming stream enough pressure to reach the higher zone (the product online says "up to 6 meters"), which would alleviate the cost of the additional tank for me. But as I have no knowledge of these matters, I don't know if that works.

I am sorry if the names of the pumps are weird, as I'm translating them from spanish.

Comment: What is the source of your water supply; we;ll or city water? If it is a well, can you increase the well pumps discharge pressure? Need much more information to even make a suggestion as to what is needed.

Comment: I have no power to change the pressure from the source. It is similar to a city water system as it comes through a big pipe, but it is far away from me, so I have a pipe attached to the main supply and runs for roughly half a mile up a slope. So for all practical purposes I have a small pipe as input.

Comment: You need more pressure; Typically the most economical solution is to use one pump with higher output pressure. Reciprocal/ positive displacement/ piston pumps are usually the most effective.

Comment: well, use the slope to drive a ram pump - then the water pumps itself...except for the water "lost"...